# Алгоритмы на орграфах

Tags: алгоритм, графы, структуры-данных

> Задан ориентированный граф,не обязательно связный.
>   1.Необходимо определить минимальное количество вершин из которых можно посетить все остальные вершины графа.
>   2. Определить минимальное количество рёбер и указать сами эти рёбра при добавлении которых из любой вершины графа можно будет попасть в другую.

Хотелось бы услышать какие-то идеи по этим пунктам. У меня вот идея для ё пункта была искать компоненты связности,но в орграфе это не будет работать.
например граф из 4 вершин,сам имеет вид (1->2,3->2,4->2)
то я показал из  какой вершины в какую можно пройти,он имеет 1 компоненту связности,но ответ на пункт 1 будет 3. Думаю решение пункта 2 связано с решением пункта 1. Так как если определить вершины из которых  я могу всё посетить,я могу потом улучшить свой граф,но как-то конкретного алгоритма я и тут не вижу. Был бы признателен услышать мысли каждого

Comment: *определить минимальное количество вершин из которых можно посетить все остальные вершины графа.* Минимальное равно нулю и не зависит от графа. Наверное, тут слово "минимальное" следует удалить?

Comment: *из любой вершины графа можно будет попасть в другую* Любую? или хотя бы одну?

Answer (score 0):

Первое -  это количество начальных вершин (sources) после топологической сортировки - таких вершин, для которых нет входящих дуг после проведения топологической сортировки.

Перед сортировкой следует провести [конденсацию](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/strong_connected_components), чтобы удалить циклы -

> Важнейшим свойством графа конденсации является то, что он ацикличен

(Цикл и вообще компонент сильной связности может быть сжат в "суперузел")

---

А второе - провести дуги от конечных вершин (стоков, sinks) в sources

P.S. Нашёл [подтверждение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305236/minimal-addition-to-strongly-connected-graph)

Comment: Что значит количество первых вершин? А если есть цикл, то как мне сделать топ.сорт?

Comment: можно ещё подумать в сторону транзитивного замыкания, [редукции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Транзитивное_сокращение), алгоритма Warshall (без доработки Флойда)

Comment: Добавил, как бороться с циклами.

Comment: Попробуй что - либо сделать. Если вам нетрудно, то  я бы хотел задавать какие-то вопросы по теме. Можете дать какой-то ваш контакт?

Comment: Нет, не стоит ;)

Comment: не работает ваш алгоритм на тесте 1-->2; 3-->4. И если просто граф  1;2;3;4. То есть без рёбер,то рёбра неправильно находятся

Comment: После топологической сортировки начальные вершины будут  1 и 2, это и есть наименьшее множество, из которых все остальные посещаются. Из конечной вершины 2 или 4 проводим одно ребро к "чужой" начальной вершине. А `какие ваши доказательства`?

Comment: В описании не было сказано,что стоки мы ведём к чужой начальной вершине, я поэтому рещил этот момент уточнить. так как ,например, в графе 1-->2;1-->3 у нас нет чужих начальных вершин и тут нужно другое правило. Это я веду к тому,что не могу найти строгой последовательности действий

Comment: Про чужую я не прав, надо к своей начальной и по ребру между компонентами. Для каждого компонента Max(sources, sinks) и ещё , видимо, `NComps` для объединения компонентов в кольцо

Comment: в этом случае вылетит пример 1-->2;3-->4. так как по вашему алгоритму необходимо 3 ребра добавить(2 так как к своей начальной + 1 между компонентами),а ответ будет 2 правильный

Comment: Так, похоже, что `Max(sources, sinks)` по всем компонентам из ссылки - верно, а я зря его решил подправить

Comment: Да,я уже сам до этого дошёл. именно максимум из стоков и истоков будет ответом. А как мне в таком случае восстановить рёбра?

Comment: По одному стоку из компонента используется для связи со истоком следующего (или со своим истоком, если компонент 1). Оставшиеся стоки или истоки соединяем с любым узлом при этих новых ребрах

Comment: Так, у меня ступор по поводу добавления рёбер, не идёт совсем. Я в итоге построил двудольный граф, где в одной доле у меня истоки, а в другой стоки. И вот теперь нужно соединять, я понимаю, что это нужно делать по алгоритму, который в вашем последнем комменте, но как это реализовать?

Comment: Начал писать, но получается то же, то и в комменте. 1->2 3->2 4->5: соединяем 2=> 4, 5 => 1, в оставшийся исток 3 вводим ребро из любого стока (хоть из своего же) 2=>3

Comment: Я понял алгоритм на словах, но не понимаю как его реализовать в коде. Как мне знать для какого стока данный исток является чужим или своим? Как это все хранить по мере добавления ребер и запоминать. Ведь мне нужно добавлять ребра последовательно, типа как гирлянда собирать

Comment: Могу прислать то, что я пытался закодить

Comment: Вот, например граф. 1->2;3->4;5->6. Я же должен добавлять ребра 2->3,4->5,6->1,но это простой пример, а если сложнее, то как мне вот сохранить эту последовательность?

Comment: Граф в целом разбивается на набор ациклических связных компонентов. Их упорядочить. Пронумеровать. Занести в список. И соединить последовательно `sink[i]=>source[i+1]`